# Perform AsyncTask before displaying the Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, fragment

I am implementing a DrawerLayout and one of the items 
or the menu of the drawer displays a gridview with images which is also a fragment.

The problem is by the time I click on the item, there is this delay or lag before the grid
of images will be showed.

Been searching for this, and I'd like to have an `AsyncTask` to make sure that the GridView  fragment
should be completely loaded before displaying which I need to have a ProgressDialog to prevent the lag
effect or to cover up the view. How do I check if the fragment is ready to be displayed? How do
I handle the `AsyncTask`? Thanks in advance.

```
            ImageGridActivity fragment = new ImageGridActivity();

            FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_planet_replace, fragment);

                   Bundle args = new Bundle();
                   args.putStringArray(Extra.IMAGES, Constants.IMAGES);
                   fragment.setArguments(args);

             ft.addToBackStack(null);
             ft.commit();
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
I am using an `ImageAdapter` to populate the images to the listview. 
                    `listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());`
```

I am using Universal-Image-Loader to handle the downloading of images and displaying it. 
`imageLoader.displayImage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could launch a new `AsyncTask` that downloads the images in its `doInBackground` method (which runs on a background thread) and dismisses the `ProgressDialog` in its `onPostExecute` method (which runs on the UI thread).

For example, in your Activity:

```
final Dialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, title, message);
//Should use DialogFragment to wrap the ProgressDialog

new AsyncTask<String, Void, List<byte[]>>(){

    @Override
    protected List<byte[]> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        List<byte[]> imageList = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFF_SIZE];
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream(BUFF_SIZE);
        //Add try - catch - finally block
        for(String targetUrl : urls){
            conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(targetUrl).openConnection();
            InputStream iStream = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            int len = 0;
            //Alternatively could use Apache Commons IO
            while ((len = iStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
               byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            imageList.add(byteBuffer.toByteArray());
            byteBuffer.reset();
        }
        return imageList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<byte[]> result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        listView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(result)); //Example
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}.execute(imageUrl1, imageUrl2, imageUrl3);
```

Comment: I am using an `ImageAdapter` to populate the images to the listview. `listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());`

Comment: Ok, I've added that. I assumed your ImageAdapter takes the list of image buffers in the constructor.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using Universal Image Loader.

Comment: I guess you could use its API to set a flag when all the images have been loaded. Check the `onLoadingComplete` method in `SimpleImageLoadingListener`.